# hide html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**JavaScript:**

```
function hide_article() {
    var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
    htmlElement.setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");
    console.log("hiding");
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="right-hand-side">
   <img src="resources/Logo.png" onmouseover="hide_article()" onclick="hide_article()"/>
</div>
```

This function is being called but the article is not being hidden. Any idea why? Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - `visibility` is a CSS rule name, not an HTML attribute.

```
htmlElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Bear in mind, though, that, unless you have good reason to use `visibility` (and there are some), you'd normally hide elements via `display` (= 'none') rather than via `visibility`.

Also, you're assuming that your function will find an element. If it doesn't, your code will error. Best to check this first:

```
function hide_article() {
    var htmlElements = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
    if (htmlElements.length) { //<-- check before continuing
        htmlElements[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
        console.log("hid element");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks I will add in that check. Can I do a check to see if it is hidden and change it to visible? I tried this:

`function hide_article() {
 var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
 if (htmlElement.getAttribute('visibility') === 'visible'){
     htmlElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  console.log("hiding")
 }
 else {
  htmlElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
  console.log("showing")
 }
};`

Comment: @user3164083 or in short:  `htmlElement.style.visibility = htmlElement.getAttribute('visibility') === 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';`

Comment: Once again, you're treating `visibility` as though it were an attribute. It's not: it's a sub **property** of the `style` **property**. So: `htmlElements[0].style.visibility = htmlElements[0].style.visibility == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';`

Answer (score 2):

This is the statement that you want:

```
htmlElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```