# How to make a hide method like jQuery hide method

Tags: javascript

I want to make a hide method for my website,just like jQuery hide method.
Can someone help me out please?
I mean:
element.hide();

Comment: Please search for similar questions before asking; this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24834624

Comment: No bro just like the jQuery hide method

Comment: *Please search for similar questions to yours.* You can use the equivalent property CSS `display: none;` in a similar manner: `element.style.display = "none";`.

Comment: function g(){var a=document.getElementById('id');   a.hide();}.          hide:function(){return this.style.display='none';} it is not working.